# "Argument is not an array" exception when setting array value using Java reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I need to create an array at running time according to the values of the input array tableParameter.

An example of my code is as follows:

```
int[] tableParameter = new int[dimension + 1];
tableParameter[0] = N;
for(int i = 1; i < tableParameter.length; i++)
    tableParameter[i] = i;
Object myArray = Array.newInstance(int.class, tableParameter);
//set the index 1 of the array with the value 100
Array.setInt(myArray, 1, 100);
```

The exception occurs in the last line of the code above:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array
```

But when I used the

```
System.out.println(myArray.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

to verify the class of myArray, it prints out int[][][][], which means myArray is definitely an array type.

So why the JVM throws the exception that myArray is not an array?

Answer (score 4):

It may be a misleading exception, but it's definitely correct to complain. If the array is an `int[][][][]`, it doesn't make sense to set the element at index 1 to value 100. For example, this won't compile:

```
int[][][][] array = new int[1][1][1][1];
array[0] = 100; // Nope...
```

You can only set an element to an `int` if it's an actual `int[]`. So if `dimension` is 0 (meaning you end up with a 1-dimensional array) and if `N` is 2 or more, the code works fine. To take reflection out of the *creation* part:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] array1 = new int[10];
        Array.setInt(array1, 1, 100); // Works fine

        int[][] array2 = new int[10][10];
        Array.setInt(array2, 1, 100); // Throws IllegalArgumentException
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the array is a multi-dimensional one instead of a one-dimensional array, is there anyway I can use Array.setInt to set the value of it?

Comment: @rolandluo: Your question makes no sense - you can only set an element of an *integer array* to an integer. Think about what you'd do *without* reflection first, then you'll see what I mean. You'll need to specify one index for each dimension, basically - with `get` calls for all but the last, and then a `setInt` call for the last one.